# Read data into a vector

Tags: r

I am trying to read [this data file](http://s.yunio.com/87HT7f).

```
x<-read.table("mydata",header=FALSE)
> mode(x)
[1] "list"
```

How can I read it as a vector? It can be done with `unlist(x)`, but I want a simpler way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Via `scan`:

```
x <- scan("mydata")
```

Simple enough?